# I have the details of services and service, and it's a relationship between them, one to many,, how to create service item

Tags: laravel

I have the details of service and service, and it's a relationship between them, one to many,

so wen i click on button details in table service , take me to service details page, where i want to use also crud on details of service.
any suggestions how to store service details where it has service_id

Answer (score 3):

You can create CRUD with dropdown from Service to create function in DetailsController with pluck.

```
// pluck(value, key)
$services = Services::all()->pluck('name', 'id');
```

And you can call it in your view file. like this:

```
<select name="service_id">
 @foreach ($services as $id => $services)
  <option value="{{ $id }}">
  {{ in_array($id, old('service_id', [])) ? 'selected' : '' }}
  {{ $services }}
  </option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

It will create dropdown with option value from service id.